# how to get a div from a external website using curl in php

Tags: php, html, curl

I am looking for curl code in which I can get a div from external website pulled in another webpage.

for example: this is the external website: http://www.uberstrike.com/public_profile/2585774

and I want to pull the data from the class "user_info".

I have seen a lot of codes in curl and none of then work.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.  We don't normally give complete solutions with no work from the OP.  The crux is, if you expect us to put our time and energy into an answer, put time and energy into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have an API.

Example code (replace the url with selections below):

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.uberstrike.com/profile/all_stats/2585774'), true);
print_r($json);
```

Scores: `http://www.uberstrike.com/profile/all_stats/2585774`:

```
Array
(
    [headshots_record] => 146
    [nutshots_record] => 91
    [damage_dealt_record] => 27060
    [damage_received_record] => 32695
    ... truncated ...
)
```

User Info: `http://www.uberstrike.com/profile/user_info/2585774`:

```
Array
(
    [name] => deadbodies
    [level] => 80
    [xp] => 5587757
    [clan_name] => E-PIPE
    [clan_tag] => EPIPE
    [accesslevel] => 0
    [creation_date] => 2011-08-17T06:40:07Z
)
```

Other stuff: `http://www.uberstrike.com/profile/user_loadout/2585774`:

```
Array
(
    [weapon_1] => 1243
    [weapon_2] => 1656
    [weapon_3] => 1370
    [melee_weapon] => 0
    [holo] => 1716
    [upper_body] => 1644
    [lower_body] => 1567
    ... truncated ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//CURL
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'WEBSITE_URL');//enter your url here
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$file_contents = curl_exec($ch); //get the page contents
preg_match($s_searchFor, $file_contents, $matches); //match the element
$file_contents = $matches[0]; //set the file_contents var to the matched elements
```